# Calculate the amount of seconds between start and end in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a task that I have to do that is to calculate the amount of seconds between a star time and a end time like a race. In the format hhmmss. With the amount of seconds finally calculate the result in hours minutes and seconds. This is a beginners course with non-objective programming, so the code I use must be simple and without any extra classes to handle time. The reason why I ask is because my calculation sometimes calculate a wrong result. I have done it like this:

```
totalAmountOfSecondsPerHour = (endHour - startHour) * 3600;
totalAmountOfMinutesPerMinutes = Math.abs((endMinutes - startMinutes) * 60);
totalAmountOfSeconds = Math.abs(endSeconds - startSeconds));
```

I use Math.abs to get rid of negative numbers.

To get the total amount in seconds I add all variables. Finally to get the result time in hhmmss I do like this:

```
resultHour = totalAmountOfSeconds / 3600;
rest totalAmountOfSeconds % 3600;

resultMinutes = rest / 60;
resultSeconds = rest % 60;
```

When I enter a starting time like 150030 and end time like 165015 the result is 1 hour 50 minutes an 15 seconds. I guess i should be more correct if it was 45 seconds!? What could be wrong in my calculation? Is there a better way or could I modify or simplify my code the make a correct result? Preciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: I would get rid of the Math.abs checks because as LastCoder pointed out, you're losing your precision there. I would just make a check to make sure endSeconds >= startSeconds. If not, exit.

Comment: Where you get you start<something> and end<something> variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you use the Math.abs()

let give you a small example: The app start at  00:00:59  and finish 2 seconds later so at 00:01:01

```
totalAmouneOfMinutesPerMinutes = Math.abs(1 - 0) * 60  = 60
totalAmountOfSeconds = Math.abs(1 - 59) = 58
```

so 60 + 58 = 118 seconds   instead of 2.  If we remove the Math.abs, we'll have:

```
totalAmouneOfMinutesPerMinutes = (1 - 0) * 60  = 60
totalAmountOfSeconds = (1 - 59) = -58
```

60 + (-58)  = 2 seconds  (like it's suppose).

Comment: Nice, would it be better if I do like this (startSeconds-60) + endSeconds to always get a correct amount of seconds? I guess I don't need any IF to check then?! And I guess I have to do the same thing with minutes also?

Comment: You have the same problem if you do  (startSecond-60) + endSecond.  Try with startSecond = 1  and endSecond = 3...

Comment: Hmm, but how should I solve it?! With IF statement to check if endSeconds is bigger, or?!

Answer (score 2):

For your seconds calc you are essentially doing

15 - 30 = -15
ABS(-15) = 15

So there's your problem.

You may want to try IF the seconds are negative THEN add 60.

Comment: Hi, could you explain some more what wrong I have done? How should I do instead?

Answer (score 1):

Take the example of start time: 1:10:10 and end time 1:11:05 obviously the difference should be 55 seconds.

But you do abs(5-10) for the seconds and get 5 seconds. And you get 1 minute 5 seconds.

You have two approaches to fix this: Get rid of the abs and instead if you get a negative result add that (negative) amount to the amount of the next 'higher' value.

So in the example instead of adding abs(-5) to 1 minute you add -5 to 1 minute, resulting in 0 minutes and 55 seconds.

While this will work it will get quite confusing.

A better approach would be: convert start and end time into seconds. Take the difference. Convert the result back into hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: Hi, I like your solution at the end, bu I'm just wonder if it's working correct? I have a start time: 150030 and a end time: 165015. The result is 1 hour 49 minutes and 45 seconds. Not 50 minutes?

Comment: Think about it: 150030 to 165030 would be 1 hour 50 minutes 00 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Those Math.abs tripped you up... Convert the time to seconds, do substraction and then convert back to hhmmss format.